# How to make a fixed caption with different margins and smaller fontsize?

Tags: captions, margins, subfloats, fontsize, letters

Im trying to make the letter of a figure caption smaller, and in addition to have different fixed margins, smaller than the rest of the text. Here's my code:

```
     \begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{filename}
\caption{some caption text}
\label{fig:SetUp}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\usepackage[font=tiny]{caption}`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

By use of the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,
            width=0.9\textwidth]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Experimental set up Diagram of the Raman spectroscopy equipment (images adapted and token from the fabricators catalogs)}
\label{fig:SetUp}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

or with image width equal to text width and package options:

```
\usepackage[font=small,
            margin={11mm,11mm}]{caption}
```

[image]